# how to get ride of a "Redeclared variable defined above without usage" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this exercise I am receiving a "Redeclared 'TOTAL' defined above without usage" error when compiling this code when am I using Pycharm but not when I compile it with Visual Studio.

I understands what the error means, but I don't understand how to fix it so I don't continue to get the error.

How would you rewrite the `TOTAL = A + int(B) + int(C)` to get ride of the error I receive? Or am I just overthinking the whole thing, as the code is working fine despite the error.

```
A, B, C = -5, '8', 7.6  # DO NOT MODIFY CONSTANT VALUES
TOTAL = int()           # DO NOT MODIFY DATA TYPE

''' PSEUDO CODE
SUM given values of A, B and C as integers, CASTING where necessary.
STORE result in variable 'TOTAL'.

Expected output:
    -5 + 8 + 7.6 = 10
'''

TOTAL = A + int(B) + int(C)
print("{} + {} + {} = {}".format(A, B, C, TOTAL))  # DO NOT MODIFY
```

Comment: Whoever's telling you to start with `TOTAL = int()` and screaming `# DO NOT MODIFY DATA TYPE` doesn't know how Python works. Pycharm is warning that person that this is not how Python works.

Comment: Code works fine for me. You might want to refactor the code to be a function where the output datatype is defined.

Comment: `int()` is just a roundabout way to write `0`

Comment: It looks like some coding challenge that was directly ported from a static-typed language into Python.

Comment: The problem is in a part your grader will probably penalize you for changing, so just leave it as it is and remember not to do that later when you're writing real code.

Comment: Or abandon this course and find a better [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the unneeded

```
TOTAL = int()           # DO NOT MODIFY DATA TYPE
```

I'm not sure what this is trying to achieve. Variables are not declared and can be assigned any type. This line doesn't constrain what can go into TOTAL later. Since you reassign `TOTAL` without having used the `0` you put into it, pycharm flags it.

You aren't overthinking the problem and you should get rid of this line. All it does is make one more assignment that a future reader would keep track of before realizing its not needed.

Python has unenforced type annotations. If you want a friendly reminder that linters like pycharm could help enforce, change it to

```
TOTAL: int
```

You can still assign anything you want to it, but gossipy IDE's will mention it.

Comment: Maybe the line could be changed to `TOTAL: int`

Answer (score 0):

The linter points at the problem correctly, you have an effectless line, `TOTAL = int()`.

If you need to specify a data type, use type annotations:

```
TOTAL: int = A + int(B) + int(C)
```

Or don't use the annotations, because in this very example the linter might derive the type anyway.